# How do I reduce viewport height after scaling down through css?

Tags: css, viewport

I'm using `tranform: scale(...)` to shrink the size on my website to match the browser width. The problem is when this happens, there's this redundant space left at the bottom of the page that's not even part of `body`. How do I get rid of it ?

Also, this extra space was originally on both top and bottom ends, but I `translate`d the page upwards so that the space is only visible at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: You cannot get rid of the space. You have to _fill_ it.

Comment: what do you tried  ?? and where are code  ?

Comment: I've tried playing around with setting browser window size manually but that doesn't do the trick. I've tried reducing the `body` height but that doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you provide the `transform: scale(...)` code in its entirety?

Comment: what about giving the body and or html a background color? Some code would make this a lot easier to test

Comment: *"I'm using tranform: scale(...) to shrink the size on my website to match the browser width."* I've never heard of anyone doing that before. why are you doing it that way? Can you give us a link to your site?

Comment: @MichaelCoker .. Its for making the width fit inside the width of a phone, for example. To get a sense of what I'm trying to accomplish, open blu-ray.com on your pc, and then on your phone. See what happens with the width.

Comment: @Ahmad why doesn't it scale automatically? most non-responsive websites will. are you scaling up or down? have you tried using a meta viewport tag?

Comment: @MichaelCoker, I have no idea why the page margins don't scale automatically. I'm scaling down. I don't know much about viewport tags so I'm hoping someone here can guide me.

Comment: Search for _meta viewport_ on this site; I'm sure you will find enough examples. And to make a website responsive; you should not resort to tricks like `scale`. Please let that be your first concern. But to answer the immediate question of where the space below the body comes from: that's because you have a style of `height:2529.62px` in the body start tag according to the inspector.